# How to handle server crash when using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: threadpoolexecutor

I catch RejectedExecutionException and handles it properly. But, I would like to know how should I catch and handle the case when the server/jvm crashes abruptly. Could anyone please help me out here ?

Answer (score 2):

There i no way you can handle that situation, since the JVM itself crashes you can't expect any of your code to run properly during that time.